# Как последовательно выполнить Get и Post запрос

Tags: java, spring, request

Делаю свое Rest-приложение, подключаюсь к Spotify Api. Я должен с помощью @Get метода получить у них код, а потом с помощью @Post метода поменять его на токен. Этот токен я должен указывать в header-е каждого запроса к их Api. Вопрос, как мне по одному нажатию на html-форме выполнить два эти действия?

Код контроллеров:
**AuthController:**

```
@RestController
public class AuthController {

    private final static String CLIENT_ID = "myId";
    private final static String CLIENT_SECRET = "mySecret";
    private final static String REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:8082/main";
    private final static String RESPONSE_TYPE = "code";
    private final static String GRANT_TYPE = "authorization_code";
    static String TOKEN = "";

    @GetMapping("/callback")
    public void getSpotifyCode(HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException{
        String getUri = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize";
        getUri += "?client_id=" + CLIENT_ID
                + "&redirect_uri=" + REDIRECT_URI
                + "&response_type=" + RESPONSE_TYPE
                + "&show_dialog=" + true
                + "&scope=" + "playlist-modify-private playlist-modify-public ugc-image-upload user-read-playback-state user-modify-playback-state user-read-currently-playing app-remote-control streaming playlist-read-private playlist-read-collaborative playlist-modify-private playlist-modify-public user-follow-modify user-follow-read user-read-playback-position user-top-read user-read-recently-played user-library-modify user-library-read user-read-email user-read-private";
        servletResponse.sendRedirect(getUri);
    }

    @PostMapping("/token")
    private void exchangeCode( HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

        MultiValueMap<String,String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        body.add("grant_type", GRANT_TYPE);
        body.add("code" , MainController.CODE);
        body.add("redirect_uri" , REDIRECT_URI);
        body.add("client_id" , CLIENT_ID);
        body.add("client_secret" , CLIENT_SECRET);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String,String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
        String spotifyResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(url,request,String.class);

        JsonNode obj = mapper.readTree(spotifyResponse);
        TOKEN = obj.get("access_token").toString()
                   .replace("\"","");
        response.sendRedirect("localhost:8082/main");
    }
}
```

**MainController:**

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    static String CODE;

    @GetMapping("/main")
    public String mainPage(@RequestParam(value = "code", required = false) String code){
        CODE = code;
        return "main";
    }
}
```

Comment: Непонятно откуда вы делаете `get` и `post`

Comment: @lampa, из html формы:

Comment: `<form th:method="GET" action="/callback">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg text-dark" type="submit">Get Rest request</button>
      </form>`

Comment: `<form th:method="POST" action="/token">
      <button type="submit">Post Rest request</button>
    </form>`

Comment: почитай тут [redirect](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно создать промежуточный метод, откуда принимать код от Spotify, и там же вызывать Post метод для обмена кода на токен:

```
@RestController
public class AuthController {

    private final static String CLIENT_ID = "myId";
    private final static String CLIENT_SECRET = "mySecret";
    private final static String REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:8082/callback";
    private final static String RESPONSE_TYPE = "code";
    private final static String GRANT_TYPE = "authorization_code";
    static String TOKEN = "";
    static String CODE = "";

    @GetMapping("/authorize")
    public RedirectView authorize(){
        String getUri = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize";
        getUri += "?client_id=" + CLIENT_ID
                + "&redirect_uri=" + REDIRECT_URI
                + "&response_type=" + RESPONSE_TYPE
                + "&show_dialog=" + true
                + "&scope=" + "playlist-modify-private playlist-modify-public ugc-image-upload user-read-playback-state user-modify-playback-state user-read-currently-playing app-remote-control streaming playlist-read-private playlist-read-collaborative playlist-modify-private playlist-modify-public user-follow-modify user-follow-read user-read-playback-position user-top-read user-read-recently-played user-library-modify user-library-read user-read-email user-read-private";
        return new RedirectView(getUri);
    }

    @GetMapping("/callback")
    public RedirectView getSpotifyCode(@RequestParam(value = "code") String code) throws IOException {
        CODE = code;
        getSpotifyToken();
        return new RedirectView("http://localhost:8082/main");
    }

    @PostMapping("/token")
    private void getSpotifyToken() throws IOException {
        String url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

        MultiValueMap<String,String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        body.add("grant_type", GRANT_TYPE);
        body.add("code" , CODE);
        body.add("redirect_uri" , REDIRECT_URI);
        body.add("client_id" , CLIENT_ID);
        body.add("client_secret" , CLIENT_SECRET);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String,String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
        String spotifyResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(url,request,String.class);

        JsonNode obj = mapper.readTree(spotifyResponse);
        TOKEN = obj.get("access_token").toString()
                   .replace("\"","");
    }
}
```